# How do I write a recursive function to get the values within a range?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to write a recursive function to get the integers in range (x, y).

Example : range(2, 9)
Expected Output : `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

The suggested solution using recursion is as follows:

```
var range = function(start_num, end_num) 
{
  if (end_num - start_num === 2) 
  {
    return [start_num + 1];
  } 
  else 
  {
    var list = range(start_num, end_num - 1);
    list.push(end_num - 1);
    return list;
  }
};

console.log(range(2,9));
```

However, as far as I understand recursions, the solution above is not recursive. Am I right? Is it possible to declare an array inside recursive function and push values into it?

Comment: it's definitely recursive, range is being called inside itself

Comment: it always returns an array, either a new one with just the low value, or that array added onto.

Comment: @dandavis , then I don't unerstand one thing... Does the code above work in the way that it declares variable "list" in each recursion iteration and clears the values added in the former iteration ?
And why the function is declared as variable's value? Is it necessary?

Comment: @castellan9168 Each iteration that the function calls itself, a new local `list` variable is created, and the old variable still exists on the call stack until the invocation in which it was created returns (in this case the `list` variable itself may get returned, so in that case it continues to live its life in the parent invocation). As for setting the function to a variable, AFAIK this is effectively the same as just writing the function name inline (except with some edge cases that can be caused by function hoisting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain what recursive programming is, let me give with a very simple example:

```
/**
 * sum up the numbers from 0 to n, i.e. 0 + 1 + ... + n
 */
function sum(n) {
  if(n===0) {
    // trivial case
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    // difficult case -> reduce the problem from n to n-1
    return sum(n-1) + n;
  }
}
```

So the recursive pattern to solve a problem is: If the problem is simple, give the answer, otherwise give a formula how to construct the solution from a slightly simpler problem of the same type.

Your code example does follow this pattern, so *it is* recursive programming.

(But note that your code will run into an infinite loop if you call e.g. range(2,3).)